# Controlling multiple CC channel with one automation curve

Tags: technique, midi, logic-pro

hope this finds you well.

Is it possible to have one automation curve that controls more than one cc channel?

Thanks in advance!

Best,

Markus

Comment: For a better answer be a bit more specific as to which DAW you are using(LPX, from the tag, ok?), any specific instruments and most importantly any external hardwares(MIDI controllers?)?